# combineLatest destructuring throws error when strictFunctionsType is enabled

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In an Angular 11.1.1 project I enabled the `strictFunctionTypes` check.

However this triggers an error with a function using the RxJs `combineLatest` as the type passed to the subscription remains an array and it is not automatically destructured into individual variables.

By disabling `strictFunctionTypes`everything works as expected.

How is it possible to refactor the following code under the `strictFunctionTypes` rule?

```
combineLatest([
      this.user$.pipe(startWith(null as User)),
      this.order$.pipe(startWith(null as Order)),
      this.invoice$.pipe(startWith([] as Faktura[])),
      this.document$.pipe(startWith([] as Document[]))
    ]).pipe(
      tap(([ order, user, invoices, docs ]: [ Partner, User, Faktura[], Document[]]) => {
        this.ordersCache$.next(order);
        this.usersCache$.next(user);
        this.invoicesCache$.next(invoices);
        this.docsCache$.next(docs);
      }),
      catchError(() => of([
        this.ordersCache$.value,
        this.usersCache$.value,
        this.invoicesCache$.value,
        this.docsCache$.value,
      ])),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe({
      // The type is (Order | User | Faktura[] | Document[])[] and does not
      // automatically destructure it into the single entities.
      // This make the strictFunctionTypes rule fail as it does
      // not match the given parameter

      next: ([ order, user, invoices, docs ]: [
        Order,
        User,
        Faktura[],
        Document[]
      ]) => {
        // ...
     },
      error: (err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    });
```

---

**UPDATE**

I updated the code with kvetis suggestion (using tap instead of map and omitting the return), but the error persist:

[image]

The issue seems related to the `catchError` as without it, there is no exception anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `return [ partner, user, invoices ];` clause since it indeed creates different type than you have. You need to tell typescript to treat the array as a tuple.

```
return [ partner, user, invoices ] as [ Partner, User, Invoice[]];
```

But in the above example, you do not really need to use `map` since you're just using it for side effects. If you use `tap`, you'll have no problems.

```
combineLatest([
      this.user$.pipe(startWith(null as User)),
      this.order$.pipe(startWith(null as Order)),
      this.invoice$.pipe(startWith([] as Invoice[]))
    ]).pipe(
      tap(([ order, user, invoices ]: [ Partner, User, Invoice[]]) => {
        this.ordersCache$.next(order);
        this.usersCache$.next(user);
        this.invoicesCache$.next(invoices);
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe({

      next: ([ order, user, invoices ]: [
        Order,
        User,
        Invoice[]
      ]) => {
        // ...
     },
      error: (err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    });
```

### EDIT: `CatchError` trouble

Seems to me I need to be explicit. The same fix applies to it as to the mapping function - you need to tell typescript to treat things as a tuple instead of an array. The fix is analogous to the first fix I proposed.

```
      catchError(() => of([
        this.ordersCache$.value,
        this.usersCache$.value,
        this.invoicesCache$.value,
        this.docsCache$.value,
      ]) as [Order, User, Faktura[], Document[]]),
```

Comment: Ich have changed as you suggested, but I still get the same exception on build.

Comment: It seems the error is with the `catchError`operator, as it generates a `PartialObserver`. I use the catchError to provide fallbackValues (previously cached) in case of error.

Comment: You need to keep typing the things as a tuple.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the hint